# ASP.NET TextBox has text but not displayed

Tags: asp.net, forms, redirect, textbox

I have some code in a master page to toggle the displayed language. When the radio button is selected the user's browser is redirected to the current page with the selected UICulture.

I'd like whatever values present in the form to persist when the language is changed but input boxes are always empty despite the .Text property containing the user's input on postback. I've tried enabling the ViewState for all the textboxes I wanted persisted but they remain blank.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection will cause a new page to load which is not postback. Therefore the textbox values cant be retained. If you want to retain the text box values then you need to keep them session .Since ViewState can only retain in the postbacks.

Comment: I would agree but I can't explain what I'm seeing in my debug sessions. on Page_Load IsPostBack is true when triggering the radio selection and the form values are available in Request.Forms